# How to compare my DateTime object with set time interval and split it afterwards

Tags: php, datetime

I've got a DateTime object that I get from database. This object represents the time during which the user has been logged in on a particular date. I need to:

1) check if this time started after 10pm/before 6am or finished after 10pm/6pm, in other words if any of this working time was in the interval from 10pm to 6am.

2) if it is, then I need to split initial DateTime object into 2 or more objects that will contain information on all time intervals spent outside of 10pm-6am interval.

I've performed this using the ->format("H") & ->format("i") and comparing integers, but it doesn't look that pretty. So I'm curious if it is possible to do this some other way, possibly using DateTime/DateInterval/other similar objects methods?
I've tried to do it this way:

```
    $login=new DateTime($row['login']);
    $logout=new DateTime($row['logout']);
    $startNightTime=strtotime("22:00:00");
    $endNightTime=strtotime("06:00");
    if(($login->format("Hi")>$startNightTime || $login->format("Hi")<$endNightTime)||($logout->format("Hi")>$startNightTime || $logout->format("Hi")<$endNightTime)){
       /*some code here*/
    }
```

Of course it didn't work because I compare the complete date, e.g. 2018-03-20 05:00 with the time 06:00 only. So it seems that I should create another DateTime object with the same date as the initial one, but with time of 10pm/6am, right? Or is there any other, more elegant way to do this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't convert to timestamps if you already have DateTime objects; you can compare objects. Maybe this https://eval.in/975601 will give you a better start?

Comment: That's great, it works! Thanks a lot. Now I just only have to take the midnight date shift into consideration and that's all. It really is working. Thank you again.